# SaltStack Error with command cmd.run

Tags: git, salt-stack

I am writing you, because of an error in the order or cmd.run highstate.

I have a pkg Maldet already installed on my server which is the master, I wish to start this `maldet -a /var/www` i have this result that can launch scans on the SRV no problem.

```
Linux Malware Detect v1.4.2
            (C) 2002-2013, R-fx Networks <proj@r-fx.org>
            (C) 2013, Ryan MacDonald <ryan@r-fx.org>
inotifywait (C) 2007, Rohan McGovern <rohan@mcgovern.id.au>
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL v2

maldet(18398): {scan} signatures loaded: 10792 (8880 MD5 / 1912 HEX)
```

but 
When I run in terminal, it launches no mistake though.
When I run hard with cmd.run or a state.sls gives me that same error:

```
SALT-MASTER: / bin / sh: 1: maldet: not found
```

You think of this error? is it normal ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Can you try to post the portion of the state file that is responsible for this functionality? Maybe trying with the full path to the maldet command will help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend following Shikhar's suggestion of using the full path to the executable. The user Salt is running as might not have Maldet in it's path.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it's work =) salt "SALT-MASTER" cmd.run '/bin/bash --login -c "maldet -a /var/www"'